# CSS block layout full screen

Tags: css, layout

Could like to make a screen layout that's broadly like this:

[image]

The entire browser window should be filled with the only two elements of "known" height being the white blocks top, left and bottom, left (for two labels, hence known will be relative to a font).  Everything else should scale with the browser window, i.e. the left bar being 15% wide, the right 85%, etc.

As a C++ developer my instinct here was to handle events in Javascript and code against the DOM but I've got a feeling this is relatively trivial with CSS.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What sort of code have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce quickly :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body,
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.left,
.right {
  float: left;
}
.left {
  position: relative;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
}
.left .label-top,
.left .label-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.left .label-top {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.left .label-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.left .content,
.left .top,
.left .bottom {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.left .top,
.left .bottom {
  height: 5%;
  background-color: gray;
}
.left .content {
  height: 30%;
  background-color: #a09898;
}
.right {
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}
.right::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="label-top">Label</div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="label-bottom">Label</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works well but on my iPad it's not quite high enough.  i.e. you have to swipe the screen down a bit to see "bottom" and "label-bottom".  In Chrome on my PC here, it's fine though.  Edit:  Nope, seems to work again.  What a mystery Safari is.

Answer (score 1):

For layouts, consider using positioning and display properties. There are many ways to create a dynamic structure, that ensures responsiveness.

For more detail, please see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971189/constructing-a-responsive-website) for some 'general' rules you may consider when creating a website.

```css
.left {
  position: absolute;
  lefT: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  background: lightgray;
}
.right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 85%;
  background: dimgray;
}
.left .fixedBlock {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
.left .filledDiv {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  background: tomato;
}
.left .filledDiv .third {
  height: 33.33%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.left .filledDiv .third:nth-child(2) {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <div class="fixedBlock">fixed height</div>
  <div class="filledDiv">
    <div class="third">dynamic height</div>
    <div class="third">with children</div>
    <div class="third">a third of its heigth</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fixedBlock">also fixed height</div>

</div>
<div class="right">right side - open me in full screen!</div>
```

Comment: I hope you can @Robinson. Pretty much anything that you 'style' could/should be done in css (height/display/positioning/shape). For manipulation of text/input handling - that's where the JS and code behind come into play :)

Answer (score 1):

So, a little base that you can start to work on top of.

As fixed height, i used `vh` and it really depends in what browsers you want to support: [vh support](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh)

Else you can use `height: 100%` of the parent or body.

```css
.left-bar {
    width: 15%;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    height: 100vh;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
}

.right-window {
    width: 85%;
    float: left;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: pink;
    
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-bar">
</div>
<div class="right-window">
</div>
```

I think this is what you want. Not sure though.

This achieves the full browser filling.

If you notice the width has `calc()` removing the 5px from the border, if you desire you can remove that and place only `15%`.

I think you only wanted a base structure and this is a really simple one, and you gotta love my color picking skills.

**Edit**: Replaced `calc()` by adding `box-sizing: border-box` thanks to @Paulie_D comment.

Comment: vh, unlike % (which I've been trying and failing with), means "vertical height" presumably.  It's the vertical height of the visible window?

Comment: it's `viewport height`, pretty self explaining :)

Comment: Not much is "self explaining" in CSS, as a beginner.

Comment: You can lose the `calc` if you use `box-sizing:border-box` to include border & padding in width/height values. - http://jsfiddle.net/krugpmjL/1/

Comment: @Paulie_D true, but I tried to "simplify" it. probably should have added the `box-sizing`. replaced `calc` in the edit.

Comment: you may want to add `html,body{margin:0;padding:0;}` to remove the scroll bars ;)