# Make Text and Image Fixed

Tags: html

I need help making this HTML code look perfect on all sizes.

If I zoom out or use a different display size than 1920x1080 it'll not look the same, and it'll look like this:

http://puu.sh/iin5w/b9aedd76e5.png

Here's the code:

```
<style>
    body {    
        background: url(http://wc24.mariocube.com/Borders/Forecast%20Channel%20Border%20Top%20Tomorrow.png) left top no-repeat,
url(http://wc24.mariocube.com/Borders/Forecast%20Channel%20Border%20Bottom%20Tomorrow.png) left bottom no-repeat,
url(http://wc24.mariocube.com/Background%20Images/Forecast%20Channel.png) left bottom no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%, 100%, auto;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <style>
        h2.pos_fixed {
            position: fixed;
            top: 28px;
            right: 1045px;
        }

        img.pos_fixed {
            position: fixed;
            top: 41px;
            right: 1400px;
        }
    </style>

    <img width="72" height="40" src="http://mariocube.com/wii/Extracted%20Data/Extracted%20Channel%20Data/Channels/Weather%20Channel/Weather%20Layout/PNG/i_triangle1.png" class="pos_fixed" />

    <b>
        <h2 style="color: #000000; font-size: 50px;" class="pos_fixed">
            <b>Today</b>
        </h2>
```

And here's the page with all the code if anyone needs it.

http://codepen.io/Larsenv/pen/yNbXKJ

Comment: stop using fixed `px` sizes then. think about using a dynamic unit like `%` or `vw` units. For more info on creating a responsive site [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971189/constructing-a-responsive-website)

Comment: you should try not to use so many image, use css when you can when creating button or text.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent {
  width:100%; 
  height:500px; 
  background:red; 
}
.child {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 33.3%; 
  height:300px;
}
.child1 {

  background:green;
}
.child2 {
  background:yellow;
}
.child3 {
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child child1"></div><div class="child child2"></div><div class="child child3"></div>
</div>
```

`position: fixed` mean it's fixed relative to the window x y position, in your example it will always be on top of your window, not the document.

what you can try is

```
.parent {
    position: relative; // this will make child div anchor to this
    width:100%; // this make this div 100% of the window. 
}
.child {
    width: 50%; // this will make div 50% of the parent. 
}
```

if you play around with %, you can arrange your image that fit all size of screen.