# Scale website correctly on big monitors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website that i'm working on locally, and it will be displayed through a projector for a presentation. Is there a way for me to scale it to the full size of the projection or if it were to be displayed on bigger screens without having to use all the media queries! I tried adding:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" />
```

But i don't think it will do the trick! Any input from you is welcomed

Edit:
Just thought i'd add that the website is in a 1000*800 container on the original size, i just want it to grow a bit whenever a screen gets bigger

Comment: there's no way to tell how big a projection screen is from javascript (or anything else)

Comment: you can zoom in and out when you first load up the page, `[ctrl]+wheel` or `[ctrl]+[=]`

Comment: you may find some help using the approaches found in this Q and A: [Constructing a responsive website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971189/constructing-a-responsive-website)

Answer (score 0):

if using Bootstrap then wrapping all content in a container-fluid div will use the full screen width (and therefore projection width).

```
<div class="container-fluid">
...// content
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but i'm not using bootstrap and the website is in a container that's 1000*800 for starter, i just want it to grow a bit each time the screen gets bigger

Answer (score 0):

I'd try getting the browser window resolution and setting the width and height accordingly if the resolution goes beyond a specific one.

```
<script>
    function setContentSize(){        
         var ww = window.innderWidth;
         var wh = window.innderHeight;

         ID.style.width = 1000 +"px";
         ID.style.width = 800 +"px"; //ID must be set in HTML
         if(ww > what you want ){
             ID.style.width = what you want +"px";
         }
    }
</script>
```

etc. You probably can work it out

And you can load it up with `window.addEventListener("resize", setContentSize);`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer mate, though wouldn't the content be messed up that way?

Comment: @J.Doe.Smith No Problem  :) How you mean? Depends how you want it. Usually content flows automatically to the size of the div it is in.

Answer (score 0):

To auto-zoom the whole page, one solution is using `transform: scale()`. The page needs to sit inside a container for this to work. First set the origin in css for the container:

```css
div#page-container {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Then change the scale factor with javascript (in my case jQuery):

```
$(function() {
  var ratio = $('div#page-container').width() / $(document).width();
  $('div#page-container').css('transform', 'scale(' + (1.0 / ratio) + ')');
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3meqydzh/).